# Two definitions of spectrums

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

In Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis Page 371, the point spectrum is defined as $\sigma_p(T)$ such that $R_\lambda(T) = (T - \lambda I)^{-1}$ does not exist.

While in my functional analysis class lecture notes, the point spectrum is defined as $\sigma_p(T) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C : ker(T - \lambda I) \neq \{0\}\}.$ The spectrum is defined as $\sigma(T) = \{T_\lambda := T - \lambda I$ is not invertible$\}.$

It seems to me that such two definitions are contradictory, that Kreyszig's definition of point spectrum is the definition of spectrum in my class lecture notes. Can someone explain to me the difference of such definitions?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is due to the fact that Kreyszig consider the spectrum of unbounded operators. So for $\lambda$ in the continuous or residual spectrum, $R_\lambda$ exists (as an unbounded operator).

The usual approach in functional analysis is for bounded operators, where you wouldn't allow for $R_\lambda$ to be unbounded, and so you would say it doesn't exist.

Comment: Kreyszig is a somewhat gentle introduction into functional analysis but there are things I have some issues with, this being one of them.

Comment: Do you mean that we consider unbounded $R_\lambda$ as "does not exist", thus they are also defined as not invertible (in my class)? While Kreyszig consider continuous spectrum and residual spectrum as $R_\lambda$ exists. That causes the difference of definition. Does that also mean that $R_\lambda$ of continuous spectrum and residual spectrum are always unbounded?

Comment: @Cameron: agreed.

Comment: @TH000: it could be bounded, but with non-dense domain. This corresponds to the case where $T-\lambda I$ is bounded below but not surjective.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Do you have any other recommended textbooks (or even university lecture notes with relatively detailed proof) for functional analysis that follows our usual approaches of defitions?

Comment: Using the second definition (where you won't allow for $R_{\lambda}$ to be unbounded), in order to show $\lambda$ is in the continuous spectrum, would it be enough to show that and inverse for $T- \lambda I$ exists, but that it's norm cannot be bounded? I seem to have done this for a certain operator, which confuses me since if an operator is not surjective, its inverse shouldn't exist. However, its inverse is unbounded

Answer (score 2):

Usually the point spectrum consists only of the eigenvalues of $T$, that is,
$$\sigma_p(T) = \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ T-\lambda I\text{ is not injective }\}.$$

Notice how this corresponds to the eigenvalues of $T$, since when $T-\lambda I$ is not injective, there exists some $x\neq 0$, such that $(T-\lambda I)x=0$, or $Tx=\lambda x$. My definition of the point spectrum is equivalent to the one you gave, namely

$$\sigma_p(T) = \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ \ker{(T-\lambda I)\neq 0}\}.$$

The definition of the spectrum is usually

$$\sigma(T) = \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ T-\lambda I\text{ is not invertible}\}.$$

Certainly $\sigma_p(T)\subseteq\sigma(T)$, but on infinite-dimensional spaces, you may have that the operator $T-\lambda I$ is injective, but not surjective: Some $\lambda$ may not be an eigenvalue of $T$, but still the operator $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible.